# Weird Cuda C installation (Ubuntu14.04)

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I just came across a weird situation after installing cuda... I literally followed every single step suggested by the nvidia website: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#axzz3H0tm46yY.... everything seems to be fine, even the samples work... however when I try to run the "hello world" program presented in Cuda by Example documentation, the terminal displays:

> The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

This is quite strange since nvcc should already be installed during the procedure suggested by the nvidia website....

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: IIRC you have to add nvcc to your path explicitly in your .shellrc (or wherever).

Comment: note that the need to modify the PATH variable is indicated by the installer at the completion of installation *and* [documented in the getting started guide you linked in the question](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#environment-setup).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PATH variable needs to include your cuda /bin directory (by default it is `/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin`)

On Ubuntu you can edit the `.bashrc` file on your `$HOME` directory, adding the following;

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If you are running a 32-bit Ubuntu version, then the paths are:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After editing the bashrc file, source it (or simply restart the terminal):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Of course, if you have changed the default location of your CUDA directory you must change the PATHS accordingly.

PLUS: there are another options to tell the system where to find a library, a program, etc. like using enviromental modules, specify the complete path to the libraries and programs manually are another options. There are many methods out there!